# How would you use windows.locatio .pathname to redirect in php

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

```
If($result){
  echo '<script>alert("Password successful updated.") Windows.location.pathname = "../pages/admin/profile";</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. JS is case sensitive.
2. It's `window.location`, not `Windows`.
3. There is missing semicolon after `alert()`.
4. You can redirect without JS with PHP `header('Location: ../pages/admin/profile');`

Comment: 4. .... but it would not show the message to the user.

Comment: 4 would only work if they did not echo out the alert. You cannot have a header after any output to the browser.